# failed to install php-integrator-base package in atom editor

Tags: php, configuration, package, atom-editor

I am new on this editor and I would like to try it for php project.

I am trying to configure this package [php-integrator-base](https://atom.io/packages/php-integrator-base) in my atom ide, but I have this error:

> The socket connection with the PHP server could not be established.
>   This means the PHP server could not be spawned. This is most likely an
>   issue with your setup, such as your PHP binary not being found, an
>   extension missing on your system, ...

[image]

This is my setup for this package:

[image]

This my php verion on my ubuntu distrib:
[image]

Anyone else have the same issue with this package ? Where am I wrong ?

---

EDIT

Since I have make the update of the package today I always have the same error but another one occured.
Indeed, an error message appears to notice that:

> Core installed failed
>   [image]

When I start the atom editor I have this message too:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Rei suggestion, I make an issue on theri github repo [here](https://github.com/php-integrator/atom-base/issues/266#issuecomment-269322338).

To solve my problem, I follow step by step a manual installation of the package and then use composer inside the package itself to install the core folder.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Unix system then go to :
`cd $HOME/.atom/packages/php-integrator-base/core/`

then you should have a directory with num version as name like 2.X.X. So :
`cd 2.1.0` and `../composer.phar install`

Answer (score 1):

I am relevantly new to this IDE as well and had errors with installation of php-integrator-base. I am using Windows and it turned out that it was an issue with my environmental path. Try the following steps:

1. Add your Git binary path to your environmental path
2. Enable sqlite on your php.ini file by adding these: `extension=php_sqlite3.dll` and `extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

If above steps do not work, try posting an issue at their [GitHub repo](https://github.com/php-integrator/atom-base/issues).

Comment: thank you for answering me. I have tried your suggestion, but sadly nothing has changed. 
Moreover, I have make the update today, and I have another error like in this [issue](https://github.com/php-integrator/atom-base/issues/266).
See my edit in my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution, which solves this "identified" issue and others only visible when running Atom in `--dev` mode.

Sadly nobody ever pointed to the fact (or noticed) this issue is caused by packages differences in between **PHP 7.0** and **PHP 7.1**. For some reason, for **PHP 7.1** some packages still reference items related to **PHP5.6**, while some other packages are expecting everything to be **PHP 7.x** related.

The solution is to upgrade the **PHP 7.0x** to **PHP 7.1**.

In Ubuntu environments you can do that by running these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove php7.0 (optional, only if you want to uninstall PHP7.0) 
sudo apt install php7.1
```

Simply restart Apache by running:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Then check your PHP version to confirm it has been upgraded:

```
php -v
```

You should get an output like this:

```
PHP 7.1.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 13:04:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.8-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+4, Copyright 
(c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

You may have to re-enable some extensions after upgrading to **PHP 7.1**. Atom may complain about these in specific (**mbString**, **SQLite** and **DOM**). Simply run these commands to install/activate them:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-mbstring
sudo apt install php7.1-sqlite
sudo apt install php7.1-xml
```

Don't forget to reactivate your old extensions as well (if any). For **PHP 7.1** in most cases it is the same "*command*" just changing "**php7**" (or "**php**") to "**php7.1**".

Once you are done with PHP, navigate to Atom's **PHP Integrator** folder and check if the folder "3.0.0" exist:

```
.atom/packages/php-integrator-base/core/3.0.0/
```

If it doesn't exist go to https://gitlab.com/php-integrator/core/tree/3.0.0, download it and extract the contents of the compressed file in the 3.0.0 folder (you may have to create it):

Then, from inside `.atom/packages/php-integrator-base/core/` you run:

```
composer install
```

Now, finally, Composer will be able to find the right packages and install all required dependencies.

Simply say "*good bye*" to the *PHP Integrator* errors that have been haunting you lately and enjoy your Atom, once again fully functional as it should be.

I hope it helps some fellow friends stop wasting time with lots of proposed *solutions* that exist online which in reality won't fix the real ***core*** of the problem. ;)

Comment: I've tried everything having written on the php integrator wiki, but only this solution worked for me, thanks. This should be included in the php integrator's "Help! It Doesn't Work!" page!

Answer (score 0):

If ./composer.phar install fails with a "missing sqlite extension", install php-sqlite extension:

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```